# Efficiently find entity count Google App Engine

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm looking for a way to get the size of my database. Right now, I've got a class method in my datastore model called `query_all` which does exactly that: it queries all entities of that model and returns them.

In my code, I call that like this:

```
query = MyModel.query_all(ndb.Key('MyModel', '*defaultMyModel'))
count = query.count()
return 'Database size: {}'.format(count)
```

Now this works, but because my database is pretty big (it has ~10,000 entities), every time I call this it takes away 20% of my Datastore Small Operations quota (I can do 0.05 million ops per day).

Is there any way for me to do this more efficiently? I think it's the `.count()` that's causing the problem and not the `query_all(...)`, but I'm not sure.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Don't use the datastore for reporting:

Rollup the data in realtime and use [Memcache](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/memcache).

#### When I want to track some consumable resource:

What I have done in the past is create a `QuotaManagementService` that I call when I create or destroy some resource.

On every insert/delete operation you increment/decrement the count for that resource.

One easy way to do with with GAE is with [MemcacheService](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass), it even has `inc()/dec()` methods for you to manipulate the counts. You can also do this async so that it doesn't affect latency.

Since Memcache is an in memory cache only you would want to [persist the information some how](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/memcache#transient). You might want to store the value in the datastore periodically, maybe from a background task. Or you could just live with recreating it when your application is updated.

#### Google Analytics

You could also pump create/delete events into Google Analytics so you can just go to the dashboard and see how many calls have been made any other detailed stuff you wouldn't have to write much code for this either.

#### Either way this can be pretty transparent with Python

You could probably just create a `Decorator` to automatically `inc/dec` the counts and not even manage it with code.

Memcache writes are free so I don't think I would write every event to a `DataStore` counter if they were frequent.

Here is some example code for using the `DataStore` directly instead of `Memcache` for [high volume writes to a counter](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters).

Comment: Ah, ok gotcha. I was really just doing it to make my deletion function was working which is why I was using the datastore, but I'll try to use MemcacheService in the future. Thanks.